# OSGi: auto generate the code for exporting services and using services in the consumer

Tags: osgi

I have been going through some tutorials of `OSGi services` and I was wondering if there is any tool to auto generate the code for exporting services and using services. Any tool to help auto generate the imported services code in the consumer part?

Kindly let me know.
Thank you.

Comment: @NeilBartlett The following ones:   [1](http://alexander.holbreich.org/2012/09/osgi_ds/) [2](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t97690.rhtml) [3](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t96740.html) [4](http://www.vogella.com/articles/OSGiServices/article.html) [5](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2009/05/12/osgi) and ofcourse [bndtools_tutorial](http://bndtools.org/tutorial.html)

Comment: All those tutorial tell you to use Declarative Services, which already takes care of the exporting and importing of services for you. So what is it that you want to have automatically generated?

Comment: @NeilBartlett I think I had presented my question itself the wrong way. I got it cleared. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to use the raw OSGi API for services. Use [Declarative Services](http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Declarative_Services) instead.